# Can't get right time in C with localtime()?

Tags: c, localtime

I have used the following code to get time and date in India, but the time i get is not the right time.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  struct timespec ts;
  struct tm *ti;
  char time_buf[80];

  // Get the current time
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);

  // Convert the time to the local time zone in India
  ti = localtime(&ts.tv_sec);

  // Format the time as a string, including the time zone offset
  strftime(time_buf, sizeof(time_buf), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", ti);

  // Print the time string
  printf("Local time in India: %s\n", time_buf);

  return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with this code and how can i get the right time.
And even with gmtime() function i get the same date and time.
I used this online c compiler- [https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler]-

https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjUgO.png)

while the actual time is 4:30 PM

Comment: An [mre] includes an explanation of what the expected behavior should be, including why the observed output is wrong. What is wrong with the output you observe? Is it in UTC? Is the format not what you want? What was the correct time in Indian when you ran the program? What does the `date` command show at or very near the same time?

Comment: If you set to the TZ environment variable to `Asia/Kolkata` and run the program, does it show the correct time?

Comment: How would the online C compiler know what time zone you are in?  It sounds like the online C compiler is running with its time zone set to UTC, which is a good choice for an online server.  (Stack Overflow's servers seem to do the same.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C date and time functions all assume a "local time zone", but it's basically a global variable, set outside of your program.

On Unix and Unix-like systems, the local time zone is set by the file `/etc/localtime`, and can be overridden on a per-process basis by the environment variable `TZ`.  That scheme works fine when the system you're using is located where you are, or where your login environment is under your control.  But you say you're using an online C compiler, meaning that you're stuck with whatever time zone it's set to.

However!  On Unix and Unix-like systems, a process can reset its own environment variables using the [`putenv`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/putenv) and [`setenv`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv) functions.  So if you make the following simple change to your program, it should work better:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...

char *zone = "Asia/Kolkata";

/* Set the time zone */
setenv("TZ", zone, 1);
tzset();

... the rest of your code ...

printf("Local time in %s: %s\n", zone, time_buf);
```

Note also the call to [`tzset`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tzset), which may be necessary to make sure that the C library catches up with the fact that you've just adjusted the `TZ` variable.

If you *do* have control over the environment where your program is running, things are a little easier, and you don't usually have to muck around with calls to `setenv` and `tzset`.  On a Unix or Unix-like system, you just have to set the `TZ` environment variable using ordinary shell techniques.  You can either invoke something like

```
export TZ=Asia/Kolkata
```

at the shall prompt before you run your program, or put that line in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` file so it's run every time you log in.

[Disclaimer: I can't promise that the `setenv` technique will work under your on-line C compiler, as it assumes that the on-line C compiler is running on a Unix or Unix-like system, with control over its own environment.  But it's likely to work.]